# Google Maps Route API V3: Bug for specific location, only when set as destination?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently using the Google Maps API to find transit routes between two locations. It works fine on almost all occassions, except when the destination is `Schiphol, Netherlands` (the national Dutch airport).

No matter what the starting location is, the Google Maps API won't find any transit routes that lead to Schiphol. Strange, because when I enter the exact same locations on http://maps.google.com, Google finds plenty of routes. Also, everything works fine when `Schiphol, Netherlands` is the starting point.

Please refer to [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tw8mmp9j/4/), or the code below.

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

directionsService.route({
  origin: 'Rotterdam, Netherlands',
  destination: 'Schiphol, Netherlands', // Change this to e.g. 'The Hague, Netherlands' and it works.
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT,
}, function(response, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    var route = response.routes[0].legs[0];
    window.alert('When Schiphol is destination: noute found!')
  } else {
    window.alert('When Schiphol is destination: no transit routes found.')
  }
});

directionsService.route({
  origin: 'Schiphol, Netherlands',
  destination: 'Rotterdam, Netherlands',
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT,
}, function(response, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    var route = response.routes[0].legs[0];
    window.alert('When Schiphol is origin: route found!')
  } else {
    window.alert('When Schiphol is origin: no transit routes found.')
  }
});
```

Comment: Weird. Does it work with a street address in Schiphol? (If such a thing exists...)

Comment: @Pekka Yes, that works. The strange thing is though that the Google Maps input autofill does suggest `Schiphol, Netherlands` as a location. And of course, it's strange that `Schiphol, Netherlands` does suffice when it's set as the origin.